# Set PopupWindow of Android between two views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, android-popupwindow

In my android activity, I have a Toolbar & a Button at the bottom of the screen. When I click the button a PopupWindow displays.
The PopupWindow contains a RecyclerView with multiple items.

The PopupWindow window should be always above the button & it should be below the Toolbar if it contains large number of items.

I was able to display the popup above the Button, but when the Recycleview contains large number of items, the popup hides the Toolbar, I need it to be below the Toolbar so the Toolbar remains visible.

How can it be done?

[image]

[image]

```
PopupWindow mPopup = new PopupWindow(context);
mPopup.setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);

RecyclerView recycler = new RecyclerView(getContext());
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = instantiateAdapter();
recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
recycler.setLayoutManager(instantiateLayoutManager());      
mPopup.setContentView(recycler);

//getAnchorView return the Button object   
PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(mPopup, getAnchorView(), mHorizontalOffset, mVerticalOffset, mGravity);
```

Comment: post some code plz!

Comment: set fixed height to recylcer view